# awk dot in regex doesn't match space

Tags: awk, posix

I want to print everything after the first whitespace. E.g. given `hello there` I want to print `hello there`, given      `what's up` I want to print `what's up`.

I wrote this fully expecting it to work:

```
{ print $0 }
match($0, /[^[:space:]].*$/) {
    print $1
}
```

I thought the regex `/[^[:space:]].*$/` would match the first non-space character, and then `.*$` would match all of the characters after it.

But the regex only seems to capture up to the next whitespace:

```
$ echo hello there | awk -f after_indent.awk
hello there
hello
```

Comment: what do you think `$1` means?

Comment: @jhnc the match

Comment: that's your problem

Comment: @jhnc I found out I have to use substr now. Do you want to post the answer or should I just self-answer?

Comment: feel free to self-answer. you could also do `awk '1; sub(/^[[:space:]]*/,"")'`

Answer (score 3):

With GNU awk, the [match function](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html#index-match_0028_0029-function) can take a 3rd argument: an array that will contain the text matched in capturing parentheses:

```bash
gawk 'match($0, /([^[:blank:]].*)/, m) {print m[1]}' file
# ...............^..............^
```

`m[1]` contains the text from the 1st pair of parentheses.

Answer (score 2):

You might also remove any leading spaces from the row. Using `*` as the quantifier, sub will return 1 and print the whole row.

```
awk 'sub(/^[[:space:]]*/, "")' file
```

If both your example strings as in file, that will print:

```
hello there
what's up
```

Answer (score 1):

`$1` is globally considered as the first [field](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Fields), it's not the match result. You have to use `substr` to get the match result:

```
{ print $0 }
match($0, /[^[:space:]].*$/) {
    print substr($0, RSTART, RLENGTH)
}
```

Comment: Note that in this particular case providing `RLENGTH` is superfluous as `substr($0, RSTART)` will give substring of line starting at RSTARTth character and spanning to end, see [substr](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html#index-substr_0028_0029-function) for details

Comment: The `.*$` in the regexp is also doing nothing useful, you could just remove it.

Comment: @EdMorton only if you then do `substr($0, RSTART)` right?

Comment: @minseong correct.

Answer (score 1):

FWIW I'd just use sed for this, e.g. given this input:

```
$ cat file
hello there
          what's up
```

and using any POSIX sed depending on whether or not you really want to duplicate lines in the output and how you want to handle lines that don't start with spaces:

```
$ sed 's/^[[:space:]]*//p' file
hello there
hello there
what's up
what's up
```

```
$ sed 's/^[[:space:]]\+//p' file
hello there
what's up
what's up
```

```
$ sed -n 's/^[[:space:]]*//p' file
hello there
what's up
```

```
$ sed -n 's/^[[:space:]]\+//p' file
what's up
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "      what's up\n \t  hello there   \t " |
```

—  trimming just the head :

```
mawk ++NF FS='^[ \t-\r]+' OFS=

|what's up|
|hello there     |
```

—  trimming head and tail :

```
gawk ++NF FS='^[ \t-\r]+|[ \t-\r]+$' OFS=

|what's up|
|hello there|
```

If you think `\v`, `\f`, and `\r` are impossible from your data, then it's a lot cleaner :

> change `[ \t-\r]+`
> — to —
> `[ \t]+`